# Fréchet Inception Distance parameters choice in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to choose the value of classifier_fn in tensorflow, I couldn't find any example about it:

```
         tf.contrib.gan.eval.frechet_classifier_distance(
                     real_images,
                     generated_images,
                     classifier_fn,
                     num_batches=1
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the inception distance, then you can use a less generic function called `tf.contrib.gan.eval.frechet_inception_distance` which doesn't ask for a `classifier_fn` argument:

```
fid = tf.contrib.gan.eval.frechet_inception_distance(real_images, fake_images)
```

However, when I had tried to use this function using `v1.14` with eager execution mode, I got errors of various kinds. So eventually, I've decided to go with a custom solution. Probably it would be helpful for you as well.

I encountered the following implementation by [Jason Brownlee](https://machinelearningmastery.com) that seems to match the description from the original paper:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from skimage.transform import resize


tf.enable_eager_execution()
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.keras.backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config))


def scale_images(images, new_shape):
    return np.asarray([resize(image, new_shape, 0) for image in images])


def calculate_fid(model, images1, images2):
    f1, f2 = [model.predict(im) for im in (images1, images2)]
    mean1, sigma1 = f1.mean(axis=0), np.cov(f1, rowvar=False)
    mean2, sigma2 = f2.mean(axis=0), np.cov(f2, rowvar=False)
    sum_sq_diff = np.sum((mean1 - mean2)**2)
    cov_mean = scipy.linalg.sqrtm(sigma1.dot(sigma2))
    if np.iscomplexobj(cov_mean):
        cov_mean = cov_mean.real
    fid = sum_sq_diff + np.trace(sigma1 + sigma2 - 2.0*cov_mean)
    return fid


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_shape = (299, 299, 3)

    inception = InceptionV3(include_top=False, pooling='avg', input_shape=input_shape)

    (dataset, _), _ = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
    dataset = dataset[:100]
    dataset = scale_images(dataset, input_shape)

    noise = preprocess_input(np.clip(255*np.random.uniform(size=dataset.shape), 0, 255))
    noise = scale_images(noise, input_shape)

    print('FID:', calculate_fid(inception, dataset, noise))
```

So we're performing the following steps:

1. re-scale images to the shape expected by `InceptionV3`;
2. transform the images using `inception_v3.preprocess_input`;
3. pass both tensors through `InceptionV3` network (without top layer);
4. use the formula [from the original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08500.pdf) with the computed features as input parameters.

---

> Here is an excerpt from the mentioned paper.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it.